# Acessing API data with javascript for website

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm new to API's and recent to programming and basically getting to grips with how things interoperate. in my project I'm currently trying to understand how to use the data. Once I have fetched the JSON how do I refer to particular elements?

For example:

Using code such as:

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('currencies');
const url = "https://api.data.com";

fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let info = data.results;
```

Returns:

```
Name: john
Address: 123 Apple close
DOB: 1/2/3
number of cars owned: 24
```

So far my code looks something like:

```js
return info.map(function(name) {
  let li = createNode('li');
  let span = createNode('span');
  span.innerHTML = `${info.name.first} ${info.address}`;
  append(li, span);
})
```

The problem is: I want to refer to the cars and do a bit of math and return this to an HTML element. How do I do this? as a design choice it seems most examples for dealing with API data work front end.

However, is it better or even possible to do this on the backend especially as my data is going to be foreseeably reliant on other sites? id like the information to be as up-to-date as possible and preferably fast. is JavaScript the best option?

Comment: add the response data that you get, as we don't know the exact data

Answer (score 0):

You can access the fields using object destructuring assignment.

```js
// Create a mock response... (remove this in production)
const fetch = () => Promise.resolve({
  "results": [{
    "name": { "first": "John" },
    "address": "123 Apple close",
    "dob": "1/2/3",
    "carsOwned": 24
  }, {
    "name": { "first": "Alice" },
    "address": "777 Vegas St",
    "dob": "7/7/7",
    "carsOwned": 999
  }]
});

const createNode = (tagName) => document.createElement(tagName);
const append = (parent, child) => parent.append(child);

const url = "https://api.data.com";
const ul = document.getElementById('currencies');

fetch(url)
  .then(({ results }) =>
    results.map(({ name: { first }, address }) => {
      let li = createNode('li');
      let span = createNode('span');
      span.innerHTML = `${first} (${address})`;
      append(li, span);
      append(ul, li);
    }));
```

```html
<ul id="currencies"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `createList()` method to create `list of elements`. Stubbed fetch api response as `response`, which you can replace with your fetch api; and also added required JS, HTML code as below:

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('currencies');
const url = "https://api.data.com";

const response = [{
  "Name": "john",
  "Address": "123 Apple close",
  "DOB": "1/2/3",
  "number of cars owned": 24
},
{
  "Name": "baca",
  "Address": "456 Apple store",
  "DOB": "1/2/3",
  "number of cars owned": 24
}];

const createList = (info) => {
for (const obj of info) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = `${obj.Name} ${obj.Address}`;
  li.appendChild(span);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
};

createList(response);
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul id="currencies">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

"the problem is i want to refer to the cars"

What do you mean by "i want to refer to the cars"? If you are accessing an api that you didn't make, then it's up to them to make the api up to date. You could also fetch the external api from your backend and then your frontend fetches it from your own backend.